# Orfeo rescale problem?

Tags: python, remote-sensing, orfeo-toolbox

I have downloaded a Sentinel image, what I histogram matched first with the following Orfeo codes (a cut the low and high 2 percentiles):

```
# Import the otb applications package
import otbApplication
# The following line creates an instance of the Convert application
Convert = otbApplication.Registry.CreateApplication("Convert")
# The following lines set all the application parameters:
Convert.SetParameterString("in", "d:/bitbucket/cnn-lcm/T33TWM_A012703_20171127T100339_B04.jp2")
Convert.SetParameterString("out", "d:/bitbucket/cnn-lcm/T33TWM_A012703_20171127T100339_B04_histcut.tif")
Convert.SetParameterString("hcp.high","2")
Convert.SetParameterString("hcp.low","2")
# The following line execute the application
Convert.ExecuteAndWriteOutput()
```

The result of the histogram seems good (notation: someway the minimum and maximum is 1 and 28000 without any pixel?)

[image: After low, high cut]

After I rescaled the image to the domain 0-255:

```
# The following line creates an instance of the Rescale application
Rescale = otbApplication.Registry.CreateApplication("Rescale")
# The following lines set all the application parameters:
Rescale.SetParameterString("in", "d:/bitbucket/cnn-lcm/T33TWM_A012703_20171127T100339_B04_histcut.tif")
Rescale.SetParameterString("out", "d:/bitbucket/cnn-lcm/T33TWM_A012703_20171127T100339_B04_scaled.tif")
Rescale.SetParameterOutputImagePixelType("out", 1)
#Rescale.SetParameterFloat("ram", 512)
Rescale.SetParameterFloat("outmin", 0)
Rescale.SetParameterFloat("outmax", 255)
# The following line execute the application
Rescale.ExecuteAndWriteOutput()
```

And the result seems strange, there are stripes in the image. What can be the reason, how can I solve it?

[image: Rescaled image]

The images were created in QGIS, with the default 2% - 98% Cumulative Min/Max cut.

Image dimensions: 10980 x 10980